# Max value not returning the correct value

Tags: java, if-statement

I can't seem to get a single MAX value for distance of my random generated points.
Because of that I cannot create the longest distance that is necessary.

```
        for(int i = 0; i < pts.length; i++) {
            pts[i] = new Point2D(Math.random(), Math.random());
            StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.RED);
            StdDraw.setPenRadius(0.008);
            pts[i].draw();

            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                double distance[] = { pts[i].distanceTo(pts[j]) };
                for(int k = 0; k < distance.length; k++ ) {
                    while(distance[k] > max) {
                        max = distance[k];
                        if(max > 0) {
                            System.out.println(max);
                            StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
                            StdDraw.setPenRadius(0.002);
                            pts[i].drawTo(pts[j]);
```

Comment: Please format this code better, and add the rest of your code.  It seems you're missing something (maybe it's just the closing curly brackets...).

Comment: So to clarify, you need max to contain the largest number inside `distance`? You have three `for loops`, so how many times do you want `max` to be printed?

Comment: So I need the maximum distance once. An printed/returned only once so the IF statement can draw the line with the largest distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, inside your inner most for loop, just check each distance and store the `max`. And once the loops are all finished, execute your drawing. In order to do so, you'll need to store the indices (the i and j) of the points somewhere globally. So something like this:

```
// declare these guys to keep track of where to draw
int maxI = 0; 
int maxJ = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < pts.length; i++){
    pts[i] = new Point2D(Math.random(), Math.random());
    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.RED);
    StdDraw.setPenRadius(0.008);
    pts[i].draw();
    for (int j = 0; j<i; j++){
        double distance[] = {pts[i].distanceTo(pts[j])};
        for (int k = 0; k <distance.length; k++ ){
            if (distance[k] > max){
                max = distance[k];
                maxI = i;
                maxJ = j;
            }
        }
    }
}

if (max > 0){
    System.out.println(max);
    StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLACK);
    StdDraw.setPenRadius(0.002);
    pts[maxI].drawTo(pts[maxJ]);
}
```

Comment: So technically I just needed to reindex I and J? and thank you so much I was suffering through out the whole day because of this!

Comment: @user3395013 yea, since your `drawTo` function depends on `i` and `j`, which are defined only while inside the for loops, you just have to store a copy of that information outside somewhere.

Comment: I was just one step behind had too much tunnel vision on the "max = distance[k]"! Thank you again!